# UWP - Image inside RadialProgressBar

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

I want to show a image inside the RadialProgressBar circle when progressing. How can I set image inside RadialProgressBar circle? Please help Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the [RadialProgressBar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwpcommunitytoolkit/controls/radialprogressbar) in CommunityToolkit. See the source code [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit/tree/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls/RadialProgressBar) on github.
Copy and paste the code to your project. Modify the XAML [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit/blob/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls/RadialProgressBar/RadialProgressBar.xaml) to add the image in the centor of the grid, then you can add this new control to your project.